# Getting AJAX request from Rails to activate

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get JQueryUI autocomplete to work in a simple text box, and I am seeing no response in the browsers. I suspect I do not have things wired up completely. I'd also like to do it as "Rails 3" as possible.
In the controller (Brand is the model, derived from ActiveRecord::Base, with field 'name'):

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @names = Brand.all.map(&:name)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

show.html.erb:

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<%= form_tag :method => :get do %>
<%= text_field_tag :name %>
<% end %>
```

show.js.erb:

```
<%= raw @names %>
```

In application.js:

```
$(function() {

  $('brand_name').autocomplete({
    source: '/brands/new.js'
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong, in terms of getting the making an AJAX request that will be handled by the Javascript I have set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, make sure that what you return from the server is really a JSON array. This is required by the jQuery UI autocomplete. Try rendering JSON  instead of Javascript:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render :json => @names }
end
```

Then give your text field a proper class or id. Otherwise, I don't know how you want to match the element with jQuery.

```
<%= text_field_tag 'brand_name', nil, :class => 'brand_name' %>
```

Lastly, correct the javascript.

```
 $(function() {
   $('.brand_name').autocomplete({
     source: '/brands/new.json'
   });
 });
```

If another problem appears, use the webkit inspector to checkout if you receive the correct data from the server and its console whether there is a javascript error.

Comment: Dave, thanks very much! This pointed me in the right direction and got it working in this case. I have problems now getting it into a second application, but at least this one works.